# Attach XML-DSIG to a PDF

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

I'm trying to implement BankID (Swedish eID provider) to sign PDF files in node.js. They have an API for both user authentication and file signing. The key is to get a PAdES file at the end of the process. First, I modify the PDF and inject placeholder zeros that will be replaced by the digital signature hexadecimal value, like so:

```
const addSignaturePlaceholder = ({pdf, reason, signatureLength = 8192}) => {
    const signature = pdf.ref({
        Type: 'Sig',
        Filter: 'Adobe.PPKLite',
        SubFilter: 'adbe.pkcs7.detached',
        ByteRange: [
            0,
            DEFAULT_BYTE_RANGE_PLACEHOLDER,
            DEFAULT_BYTE_RANGE_PLACEHOLDER,
            DEFAULT_BYTE_RANGE_PLACEHOLDER,
        ],
        Contents: Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(0).repeat(signatureLength)),
        Reason: new String(reason),
        M: new Date(),
    });

    return signature;
};
```

Then I send this PDF - converted to bytes and Base-64 encoded to BankID. After the signature process is completed, BankID returns XML-DSig.

My question is, what do I do next? Is it possible to attach the signature to the PDF directly?

Here is the abbreviated BankID response:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
     <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
     <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
     <Reference Type="http://www.bankid.com/signature/v1.0.0/types" URI="#bidSignedData">
        <Transforms>
           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>LCJtWcNyKWs03NkV0mh2OHB4/9bX1kS8mWLdWIDNoHk=</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
     <Reference URI="#bidKeyInfo">
        <Transforms>
           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>base64digest</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>sigbase64</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo Id="bidKeyInfo">
     <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>signercertinBase64</X509Certificate>
        <X509Certificate>intermediateCRinBase64</X509Certificate>
        <X509Certificate>intermediate2</X509Certificate>
     </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
  <Object>
     <bankIdSignedData xmlns="http://www.bankid.com/signature/v1.0.0/types" Id="bidSignedData">
        <usrVisibleData charset="UTF-8" visible="wysiwys">Q29udHJhY3QgYmV0d2VlbiBBIGFuZCBC</usrVisibleData>
        <usrNonVisibleData>encodedPDF</usrNonVisibleData>
        <srvInfo>
           <name>...</name>
           <nonce>...</nonce>
           <displayName>...</displayName>
        </srvInfo>
        <clientInfo>
           <funcId>Signing</funcId>
           <version>...</version>
        </clientInfo>
     </bankIdSignedData>
  </Object>
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a detached signature, which means having two files. That said, `encodedPDF` is not much of an identifier for the separate data. I presume you input "Contract between A and B" yourself.